# Restart Runnable Variables Android

Tags: java, android, timer, runnable

I want to do something that i am not sure can be done, and so far i haven't found any good answers to my question.

Here is my situation:
 - I have implemented `Timer` as a `Handler` that has `Runnable` that is calling itself every 1s.
 - I need now to implement a method like `Timer.restart()` that can restart my `Runnable's` params.

**Here is my code so you can see it, and better understand what i have tried to achieve**

```
private Runnable rStartCPRTick = new Runnable() {
    public int seconds = 0;
    public int minutes = 0;
    public int hours = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(++seconds%60 == 0) //increases the time by one second
            if(++minutes%60 == 0)
                hours++;
        mActivity.updateCPRTime(formatHHMMSS(hours,minutes,seconds));
        mStartCodeHandler.postDelayed(this,1000); // tick again in 1s
    }

    public void restartCPRTick(){
          seconds = 0;
          minutes = 0;
          hours = 0;
    }
};
```

My runnable, i want to be able to call `resetCPRTick()` from outside `Runnable` and then call run that starts from the beggining.

Is such thing possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your runnable is a class.  You can add any methods to it you want.  Just keep a reference to it around and call a method that does it (to do this you probably want to make it a inner class rather than an annonymous class).

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, it's an anonymous class, but i think i know a solution. 
I will create my own subclass of Runnable that has a method called restart() so that every class that implements that class will have to override that method. :D

Comment: Then make it noon anonymous. There's no reason a class every has to be anonymous

Comment: Yes, but then  i will have more classes, my way that i have done it, subclassing requires only 1, and that's my style of coding, so i kinda like it now.